# Installed Bidet In Bathroom But Light Flickers, How to fix?

Tags: electrical

Installed Electric Bidet In parallel AC to one led light in the bathroom, but light sometimes flicker when Bidet runs. How to fix?

Comment: I would have thought that wiring the bidet to a light circuit would be illegal in most countries.  I trust you have an RCD or equivalent in the circuit.

Comment: are the lights on a dimmer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bidets can use anywhere from 600 to 1400 watts of power. Wiring it in parallel with an LED light will cause the light to flicker when the heat cycle operates causing  slight voltage drop which LED lights hate because of their sensitive electronics. You'll have to live with it unless you want to experiment with different lights or run a dedicated circuit or use a different circuit for the bidet. You probably wouldn't have the problem with an incandescent light.

Answer (score 1):

Could be faulty wiring.  Bidets can pull a bit of power, and if any connections were poorly made they could be suffering series **arc faults** - which can burn your house down but will also create spikes the LEDs won't like.

I would say review all work and review the technique used for such work.  The only thing worse than backstabs is wire nuts not properly used. And torque screwdrivers are now Code, for good reason.